# Is it safe to move the .ethereum data directory?

Tags: storage, datadir

I just bought a new 1TB SSD drive and I would like to move my .ethereum directory from the 60GB to the 1000GB HD. Is it safe to simply move the directory?

Comment: Which client are you using? Geth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be fine (I've done it several times with Parity's data directory and with `geth`). However, if the logical location of the directory has moved, you need to make sure your Ethereum client knows to look for the data directory in the new location. `geth` is perfectly happy with symlinks. Alternately, you can use the `--datadir` option when starting `geth`.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Yes

Have you tried it? Apart from the time it takes to swap your drives in and out, there's very little risk in attempting it.

I recently moved my data directory to a new drive without incident. Some clients might react poorly, but geth should work fine.

Feel free to start a new question if you run into a specific issue.